# Monitor processes during startup that changes umask

Tags: macos, permission, startup

Two days ago I began noticing permission problems with my web projects, I had to keep resetting permission so apache could read or write. What a pain! After hours of confusion I finally realized that any file created by a process I own receives the permission of 700 and my umask was set to 077.

I found the OSX 10.3 and up instruction to change my default umask. I made the change and restarted my computer... and again 077. I manually set my umask to 022 like the default would have it be, and about an hour later, while writing this I check my umask and it's set back to 077.

So my long-winded question is **how can I monitor my system for a process that updates my umask?** I would love to launch an agent at the beginning of startup that will check watch and log any process that updates my umask. Is this possible?

Comment: I have found the umask is being changed by iTerm2 whenever starting a new session. An update / bugfix has been released. However, I would like to give someone points if they have an answer to my question...

Answer (score 1):

after further research I realized that it was my Terminal app (iTerm2) setting the umask. This was due to a bug and an update was already available. This issue caused a great deal of stress and setback.